# How to automatically save maximized window when saving animation when using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444025/animated-plot-with-subplots-in-matplotlib?noredirect=1&lq=1) link, they explain how to use subplots and save the result as an .mp4 file. It works great. However, it saves the video as if the window were not maximized. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439588/how-to-maximize-a-plt-show-window-using-python), they explain how to automatically maximize when displaying, that is, when using plt.show(), which works. But again, when saving automatically by using .save, it does not save the maximized the version. Does anyone know how to do that (if it is not too complicated)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the dimensions you want by adjusting `figsize` using:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10))
```

where `20` and `10` are respectively width and height of the figure in inches
and you can also provide a `dpi` option (defaults to `100`) :

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 10), dpi=80)
```

When you save the figure, `dpi` option is still available:

```py
plt.savefig("test.png", dpi=80)
```

For animations, it's the same:

```py
ani.save("test.mp4", dpi=80)
```